# Bison C++ - subtracting

Tags: c++, bison

I'm making a simple calc using lex and bison. What should it do is to parse every mentioned subtracting - `1 - -1`, `1- 1`, `1--1`, and what's the most important: `1-1`. The first three cases are working, but in the last one it looks as if it separated the sentence into numbers `1` and `-1` without a sign between them and that's why there is an error.
I read about precedence and how to use it, nothing has worked.

Below is my shortened code, ready to copy:

.l file

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"

void yyerror (const char* s);
int yylex();
%}

%%
[-+*/%\^()\n] { return yytext[0]; }
[0] {yylval = 0; return number;}
[-]?[1-9][0-9]* {yylval = atoi(yytext); return number;}
%%

int yywrap(void) {return 1;}
void yyerror (const char* s) {;}
```

.y file

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

void yyerror (const char*);
int yylex();
%}

%token number


%right NEG
%left '-'

%%
program: 
       | line program
       ;

line: '\n'
    | expression '\n' { std::cout << "Score: " << $1 << "\n";   }
    ;

expression: number { ; }
          | expression '-' expression { $$ = $1-$3; }
          | '-' expression %prec NEG { $$ = -$2; }
          ;
%% 

int main (void) {
    return yyparse();
}
```

input and output:

```
1- - 1
  Score: 2
1--1
Score: 2
1-1
<here is an error>
```

Comment: The problem is that `1-1` tokenizes to two consecutive numbers, values `1` and `-1`, and your expression rules don't allow two consecutive numbers.  In C, there are no negative [integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1).  Maybe you should decide that you don't recognize them either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your precedence annotation didn't change anything for you because the rule `'-' expression` isn't actually used in `1-1`. The problem with that input is that the parser only sees two integer tokens and nothing you can do in the parser can change that.

Instead you'll need to make the lexer produce three tokens for that input instead of two. You can do by simply removing the `[-]?` from your rule for `number` tokens. With that change `1-1` will be tokenized as `number, '-', number` and your parser will work.

Note that this will still allow negative numbers because your `'-' expression` rule handles that - it just won't treat negative numbers as a single token, which is fine.

Comment: It will also treat `- 1` with a space as `-1` — which shouldn't matter much.